# Using monit for a process that doesn't background/run as a daemon

Tags: linux, monitoring, monit

I"m using montit for other processes I need to run, but I have a process which doesn't run as a daemon, and I can't figure out how to monitor it with monit

Answer (score 2):

Current versions of monit allow you to match process strings using the `matching "string"` directive instead of the PID...

```
check process n2n-edge
        matching "/usr/sbin/edge"
        start program = "/root/tools/edge.87.server"
        stop program = "/usr/bin/killall edge"
        if 10 restarts within 11 cycles then timeout
        if cpu usage > 95% for 11 cycles then restart
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the byproducts of the process.

You could, for example, monitor the existence of a lock file, the modification time of a directory, or something that is modified or created by your process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `start-stop-daemon` and use the `--make-pidfile` option to create a pidfile. If this is not possible you may directly check the service, for example:

```
check host localhost with address 127.0.0.1
start program = "/etc/init.d/postfix start" 
stop program = "/etc/init.d/postfix stop" 
if failed port 25 protocol smtp then restart
```